# how to include a css file in a wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to include a new style sheet in my wordpress site for all pages. I would like to do it through the same template style.css is included. But I cant really figure out how style.css is being included. I am using 2012 theme

I see the style.css in the theme directory. But how is it being included? Basically from which file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for it is on line 152 of functions.php.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

To include your own CSS file use:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-stylesheet.css' );
```

This would be equivalent to /wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/my-stylesheet.css

The code goes inside the twentytwelve_scripts_styles function although I'd encourage you to create a child theme instead. In which case you'd enter the following in your child theme's functions.php

```
function wpse_load_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-stylesheet.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_css' );
```

Comment: Pleased I could help.